# Как передать значения из одного маппера в другой (Java Spring)

Tags: java, spring, сессия

у меня есть два мапера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String main(){

    return "index";
}
```

и второй

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model
        , @RequestParam(value = "text",required = true)String text) {
    List<Book> books = bookMapper.findByCondition(text);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

как передать `List<Book> books` в первый контроллер

Comment: А что будет сделано с этим списком? Он будет просто выведен в качестве результата или у него будет какая-то обработка?

Comment: пока только вывод в на страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда делается перенаправление запроса с помощью

```
return "redirect:/"
```

то создается новый запрос и все аттрибуты предыдущего запроса не передаются, хотя вы можете передавать аттрибуты если использовать [`RedirectAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

Самый простой способ это передать в этом же запросе

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model
        , @RequestParam(value = "text",required = true)String text) {
    List<Book> books = bookMapper.findByCondition(text);
    model.addAttribute("books", books); 
    return "forward:/";
}
```

Comment: не совсем понял, точнее не понял

Comment: теперь надеюсь стало понятно?

Comment: спасибо понял, но как насчет redirect есть знаете, где можно об этом почитать

Comment: по ссылке там есть пример